# Deep Replace values in one object with another object - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object, lodash

Hi i am working with javascript/node.js. I have two data objects. (Please note that  the real objects are much more complex than this.)

```
    const original = {
        'totAmount': 10,
        'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz',
        'potentialPaid': 10,
        'depositAmount': 10,
        'payment': {
            'amount': 10,
             'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz',
            'details': {
                'amount': 10,
                'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz',
                'statusHistory': {
                    'amount': 10,
                    'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz'
                }
            }
        },
        'coupon': {'test': 1000}
    };
```

and

```
const dataToUpdate = {
        'totAmount': 65,
        'potentialPaid': 65,
        'depositAmount': 65,
        'payment': {
            'amount': 65,
            'details': {
                'amount': 65,
                'statusHistory': {
                    'amount': 65
                }
            }
        },
        'coupon': {}
    };
```

I want replace all the values in `original` from `dataToUpdate` with the same keys .

My expected result is

```
    const original = {
        'totAmount': 65,
        'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz',
        'potentialPaid': 65,
        'depositAmount': 65,
        'payment': {
            'amount': 65,
            'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz',
            'details': {
                'amount': 65,
                 'testVal': 'zzzzzzzz',
                'statusHistory': {
                    'amount': 65,
                    'testVal': 'zzzzzzzzz
                }
            }
        },
        'coupon': {}
    };
```

- All the values with the same keys in original object should be replaced by the other object values.

I was looking at various solutions like , `Object.assign()` `.merge` in `lodash` and many others.

I am stuck with this for more than 3 hours now and still i cannot find any solution .

Is there any Default javascript function there available doing this kind of a thing ? , please help.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think you are trying to merge two objects with two different criteria at the same time. What I mean is, you are trying to keep the original.payment.testVal in your result object and then you want to omit the original.coupon.test in the result object. So how would your helper function (Object.assign, _.merge, etc) know when you want to keep a field from the original object and when you don't?

Comment: mm i guess if the object is empty i want to replace and if the object is not empty i want to merge

Comment: I am not aware of a function (either native nor from a lib) than can help you achieve that because of the custom criteria you are applying. You will need to implement your own merge function if that is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I found that since version 4.0.0 [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) has a mergeWith function that lets you apply a custom criteria for the merge.

I am adding here a jsfiddle that works for your example but that might need to be adjust a little to cover some other scenarios (I am not sure though).

The function from the jsfiddle that let you customize the merge criteria is this:

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isEmpty(srcValue)) {
    return srcValue;
  }
  else {
    _.merge(objValue, srcValue);
  }
}
```

And here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9g2L60g/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash's [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) is recursive out of the box. `_.mergeWith()` accepts a customizer function. If the customizer returns `undefined`, `_.mergeWith()` uses it's default merging rules.

```js
const original = {"totAmount":10,"testVal":"zzzzzzzz","potentialPaid":10,"depositAmount":10,"payment":{"amount":10,"testVal":"zzzzzzzz","details":{"amount":10,"testVal":"zzzzzzzz","statusHistory":{"amount":10,"testVal":"zzzzzzzz"}}},"coupon":{"test":1000}};
const dataToUpdate = {"totAmount":65,"potentialPaid":65,"depositAmount":65,"payment":{"amount":65,"details":{"amount":65,"statusHistory":{"amount":65}}},"coupon":{}};

const result = _.mergeWith(original, dataToUpdate, (objValue, srcValue) => _.isEmpty(srcValue) ? srcValue : undefined);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom function to replace nested properties in the object including array, object and date.

```js
const a = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'john@mail.com',
  location: {
    country: {
      name: 'Japan',
      abbr: 'JP',
    },
    place: 'Tokyo',
  },
  phone: [123, 456],
  age: new Date('2021-05-15T15:28:37.453Z'),
};

const b = {
  email: 'johndoe@mail.com',
  location: {
    country: {
      name: 'Canada',
      abbr: 'CA',
    },
  },
  phone: [123],
  age: new Date('2001-08-15T15:28:37.453Z'),
};

const superReplace = (object, value) => {
  let replace = {};

  Object.keys(object).forEach(prop => {
    if (value[prop] !== undefined) {
      if (Array.isArray(object[prop])) replace[prop] = value[prop];
      else if (value[prop] instanceof Date) {
        replace[prop] = value[prop];
      } else if (typeof object[prop] === 'object' && object[prop] !== null) {
        replace[prop] = superReplace(object[prop], value[prop]);
      } else replace[prop] = value[prop];
    } else replace[prop] = object[prop];
  });

  return replace;
};

console.log(superReplace(a, b));
// {
//   name: 'John Doe',
//   email: 'johndoe@mail.com',
//   location: { country: { name: 'Canada', abbr: 'CA' }, place: 'Tokyo' },
//   phone: [ 123 ],
//   age: 2001-08-15T15:28:37.453Z
// }
```